# How can I fix the insert method in my linked list so that the first element isn't inserted twice?

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm writing a program with multiple functions using linked lists, one of which is printing a linked list. When I do print my linked list, for some reason the first element is printed twice indicating it's been inserted twice. Here is my insert method:

```
public void insert(E element)
    {
        Comparable<E> elemC = (Comparable<E>) element;
        ListNode new_node = new ListNode(elemC);
        if(first == null)
        {
            first = new ListNode(elemC);
        }
        ListNode last = first;
        while(last.next != null)
        {
            last = last.next;
        }
        last.next = new_node;
    }
```

and here are some of my other methods that may possibly be related to the problem such as my readData method and the method that prints the list:

```
public void readData(SinglyLinkedList<Item> list)
    {
        FileInput inFile;

        String fileName = "file20.txt";
        int id, inv;

        inFile = new FileInput(fileName);

        int howMany = inFile.readInt();
        for (int k = 1; k <= howMany; k++)
        {
            id = inFile.readInt();
            inv = inFile.readInt();
            list.insert(new Item(id, inv));
        }
    }
 /**
     *  Print the contents of the entire linked list
     */
    public void printList()
    {
        ListNode temp = first;
        while (temp != null)
        {
            System.out.println(temp.getValue() + " ");
            temp = temp.getNext();// go to next node
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Here is the text file that is being read:

```
20
       196        60
     18618        64
      2370        65
     18410        56
     18465        27
     19967        45
     17911        96
       184        14
     18871        69
     14088        92
     18061         3
       206        31
     13066         8
     12705        14
     15917        51
     15814        60
     15320        82
      8303        90
      7282        73
     12328        63
```

which yields this result at the moment:

```
Id=196,Inv=60 
Id=196,Inv=60 
Id=18618,Inv=64 
Id=2370,Inv=65 
Id=18410,Inv=56 
Id=18465,Inv=27 
Id=19967,Inv=45 
Id=17911,Inv=96 
Id=184,Inv=14 
Id=18871,Inv=69 
Id=14088,Inv=92 
Id=18061,Inv=3 
Id=206,Inv=31 
Id=13066,Inv=8 
Id=12705,Inv=14 
Id=15917,Inv=51 
Id=15814,Inv=60 
Id=15320,Inv=82 
Id=8303,Inv=90 
Id=7282,Inv=73 
Id=12328,Inv=63
```

Please help me, I'm lost on what could be the problem. I've tried eliminating the code in my insert method line by line, but I still couldn't find the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Edit: So I tried the tip that was suggested, but for some reason now my program won't read my input. Here is the method associated with user input:

```
public void mainMenu (SinglyLinkedList<Item> head)
    {
        String choice;
        ConsoleIO console = new ConsoleIO();
        do
        {
            System.out.println("Linked List algorithm menu\n");
            System.out.println("(1) Read data from disk");
            System.out.println("(2) Print ordered list");
            System.out.println("(3) Search list");
            System.out.println("(4) Delete from list");
            System.out.println("(5) Clear entire list");
            System.out.println("(6) Count nodes in list");
            System.out.println("(7) Print list backwards");
            System.out.println("(Q) Quit\n");
            System.out.print("Choice ---> ");
            choice = console.readLine();  // kludge to ensure choice.charAt(0) > 0

            System.out.println();

            if ('1' <= choice.charAt(0) && choice.charAt(0) <= '7')
            {
                switch (choice.charAt(0))
                {
                    case '1' :
                    readData(head);
                    break;
                    case '2' :
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println("The tree printed inorder\n");
                    head.printList();
                    System.out.println();
                    break;
                    case '3' :
                    testFind(head);
                    break;
                    case '4' :
                    testDelete(head);
                    break;
                    case '5' :
                    head.clear();
                    break;
                    case '6' :
                    System.out.println("Number of nodes = " + head.size ());
                    System.out.println();
                    break;
                    case '7' :
                    head.printBackwards();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        while (choice.charAt(0) != 'Q' && choice.charAt(0) != 'q');
    }
```

and here is my main method which calls this method:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        OrderedList test = new OrderedList();
        SinglyLinkedList<Item> list = new SinglyLinkedList<Item>();

        test.mainMenu (list);
    }
```

and here's my updated insert method, which is the only thing I changed:

```
public void insert(E element)
    {
        Comparable<E> elemC = (Comparable<E>) element;
        ListNode new_node = new ListNode(elemC);
        if(first == null)
        {
            first = new_node;
        }
        ListNode last = first;
        while(last.next != null)
        {
            last = last.next;
        }
        last.next = new_node;
    }
```

Comment: There's no reason to continue to the rest of the function after assigning to `first`. If you do, you're essentially inserting the same node again on the last line of the function. Try returning after assigning to `first`, and see if that helps.

Comment: I love you. Thank you so much that worked.

Comment: You're welcome! If you're not sure why that worked, try drawing it out on a piece of paper and walking through the code line-by-line to see why you insert the node twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem looks to be in these lines:

```
 ListNode new_node = new ListNode(elemC);
        if(first == null)
        {
            first = new ListNode(elemC);
        }
```

You are using new twice for the first element which is causing the duplicate insertion.

Instead of creating a new object in if condition , you just assign the reference.

```
 ListNode new_node = new ListNode(elemC);
        if(first == null)
        {
            first = new_node ;
        }
```

Comment: I took your advice, but I'm not sure whether it works. Can you take a look at my edit if it's not too much trouble?